# How to use Java Mission Control

Tags: java, java-mission-control

Hello I am a beginner in `Java` and had finally downloaded `Java Mission Control`. However I am not familiar with it and have trouble creating a basic setting for me to practice coding.

I have started programming with `Python 3.4` and used `Pycharm` but obviously this is a lot different. Searching didn't help much since typing `Java Mission Control` didn't bring up much but complicated tutorials about advanced questions.

Right now all I can do is start up `Java Mission Control` that has a black page with no way to type and "The JVM" on the left column. Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: Java Mission Control is **not an IDE**! It's a set of monitoring tools for a running Java application. To get a Java IDE simply download NetBeans, Eclipse or IntelliJ.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Mission control is not for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pycharm is an IDE, and Java Mission Control is not.

It seems that you are looking for a Java IDE. The 3 most well-knowns are [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/) and [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/downloads/).

IntelliJ is from JetBrains, just like Pycharm. That one might look the most familiar to you.

Answer (score 0):

Java Mission Control is a rather advanced tool for debugging and diagnostics, not a development environment.

At your current level I would suggest to start with BlueJ to get an idea of how Java works, and then when you are ready upgrade to a full featured IDE.

I would suggest using IntelliJ then, as this would mean that the debugger would be very familiar to you as they deliberately built and the PyCharm Python debugger on the same foundation.